# Python how to recieve SIGINT in Docker to stop service?

Tags: python, docker, signals, sigint, sigkill

I'm writing a monitor service in Python that monitors another service and while the monitor & scheduling part works fine, I have a hard time figuring out how to do a proper shutdown of the service using a `SIGINT` signal send to the Docker container. Specifically, the service should catch the `SIGINT` from either a docker stop or a Kubernetes stop signal, but so far it doesn't. I have reduced the issue to a minimal test case which is easy to replicate in Docker:

```py
import signal
import sys
import time

class MainApp:

    def __init__(self):
        self.shutdown = False
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.exit_gracefully)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.exit_gracefully)

    def exit_gracefully(self, signum, frame):
        print('Received:', signum)
        self.shutdown = True

    def start(self):
        print("Start app")

    def run(self):
        print("Running app")
        time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        print("Stop app")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = MainApp()

    app.start()

    # This boolean flag should flip to false when a SIGINT or SIGTERM comes in...
    while not app.shutdown:
        app.run()

    else: # However, this code gets never executed ...
        app.stop()
        sys.exit(0)
```

And the corresponding Dockerfile, again minimalistic:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
COPY test/TestGS.py .
STOPSIGNAL SIGINT
CMD [ "python", "TestGS.py" ]
```

I opted for Docker because the [Docker stop command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) is documented to issue a SIGINT signal, waits a bit, and then issues a SIGKILL. This should be an ideal test case.

However, when starting the docker container with an interactive shell attached, and stopping the container from a second shell, the stop() code never gets executed. Verifying the issue, a simple:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{.State.ExitCode}}' 64d39c3b
```

Shows exit code 137 instead of exit code 0.

Apparently, one of two things is happening. Either the `SIGTERM` signal isn't propagated into the container or Python runtime and this might be true because the exit_gracefully function isn't called apparently otherwise we would see the printout of the signal. I know that you have to be careful about how to start your code from within [Docker to actually get a `SIGINT`](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/), but when adding the stop signal line to the Dockerfile, a global `SIGINT` should be issued to the container, at least to my humble understanding reading the docs.

Or, the Python code I wrote isn't catching any signal at all. Either way, I simply cannot figure out why the stop code never gets called. I spent a fair amount of time researching the web, but at this point, I feel I'm running circles, Any idea how to solve the issue of correctly ending a python script running inside docker using a `SIGINT` signal?

Thank you

Marvin

Comment: The main loop is running on a `shutdown` local variable, which never changes, as opposed to `app.shutdown`, which should.  But: are you seeing the "Received:" message, or is the signal getting lost entirely?

Comment: Thanks for pointing at the local variable glitch. However, even with that fix applied, I am still not getting the "Received:" message.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solution:

The app must run as PID 1 inside docker to receive a SIGINT. To do so, one must use ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD. The fixed Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
COPY test/TestGS.py .
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "TestGS.py"]
```

Build the image:

```
docker build . -t python-signals
```

Run the image:

```
docker run -it --rm --name="python-signals" python-signals
```

And from a second terminal, stop the container:

```
 docker stop python-signals
```

Then you get the expected output:

```
Received SIGTERM signal
Stop app
```

It seems a bit odd to me that Docker only emits SIGTERMS to PID 1, but thankfully that's relatively easy to fix. The article below was most helpful to solve this issue.

https://itnext.io/containers-terminating-with-grace-d19e0ce34290

Comment: (`ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are joined together to form a single command, and whatever that command is will run as pid 1 within the container.  To me it seems like the most substantial difference from your original Dockerfile is whether you specify a `STOPSIGNAL`.)

Comment: In this case you are right, because python3:slim has no entrypoint. But it's not always the case, as some images have `/bin/sh -c` as entrypoint. Setting CMD ["python"] in those cases yields a final form of `/bin/sh -c "python"`.